# Fastest way to check if values in one table does not exist in another based on multiple values

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

This is probably easy but i have been racking my brain. I have two tables (TEMP_PARTY and GTT_PARTY).

TEMP_PARTY AND GTT_PARTY have the following columns => system, case_num, party_id, party, role.

What I am trying to do is find all values from TEMP_PARTY that do not exist in GTT_PARTY based on a unique combination of System, case_num and party_id.

Hence, i want to pull all parties from TEMP_PARTY where I have no record in GTT_PARTY. A record is uniquely identified by data in the three columns (System, case_num and party_id).

Speed is a HUGE concern for me. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS` like below

```
select * from TEMP_PARTY
where not exists 
(
select 1 from GTT_PARTY
where System = some_val
and case_num = 3
and party_id = 7
)
```

Also, You can use `MINUS` operator (If I am not wrong `Oracle` has it and it's same as `EXCEPT` in `SQL Server`) like

```
select * from TEMP_PARTY
where System = some_val
and case_num = 3
and party_id = 7

MINUS

select * from GTT_PARTY
where System = some_val
and case_num = 3
and party_id = 7
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thank you! I ended up using minus and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

One approach is an anti-join pattern:

```
SELECT t.system
     , t.case_num
     , t.party_id
     , t.party
     , t.role
  FROM TEMP_PARTY t
  LEFT
  JOIN GTT_PARTY g
    ON g.system   = t.system
   AND g.case_num = t.case_num
   AND g.party_id = t.party_id
 WHERE g.system IS NULL
```

This is an "outer" join, returning all rows from **`t`**, along with all matching rows from **`g`**, except we've added a predicate in the `WHERE` clause which effectively *excludes* all rows that had a match. So what we're left with is rows from **`t`** that don't have any matching row(s) in **`g`**.

This isn;t the only way to get the result. There are several other approaches, for example, you can return an equivalent result with a query using a `NOT EXISTS` and correlated subquery.

```
SELECT t.system
     , t.case_num
     , t.party_id
     , t.party
     , t.role
  FROM TEMP_PARTY t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM GTT_PARTY g
          WHERE g.system   = t.system
            AND g.case_num = t.case_num
            AND g.party_id = t.party_id
       )
```

---

For best performance, we'd want to see an index (with leading columns of)

```
... ON GTT_PARTY (system,case_num,party_id)
```

<strike>`EXPLAIN` output will show the execution plan.</strike>

(I was thinking this was for MySQL; these same queries will work in Oracle as well.)